# JFrame vs JPanel and then JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a program which displays one ellipses (Ellipse2D) .

Should I directly add the ellipse to a JFrame or should I add it to a JPanel, which ultimately is added to the JFrame? (Adding a JPanel is more work)

Which one will help me in the long run? (I might consider putting keybindings.)

To make things clearer:

Should I do:

```
public class Test extends JFrame{ // This is a JFrame

Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(); // I have an ellipse class

Test(){

...
add(ellipse);
...

}

}
```

Or should I do:

```
public class Test extends JFrame{

Test2 test2 = new Test2();

Test(){
...
add(test2)
...
}
}

public class Test2 extends JPanel{ // This is a JPanel

Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(); // I have an ellipse class

Test2(){

...
add(ellipse);
...

}

}
```

Comment: I don't see this question as simply answerable. What works best is what is needed in that situation. If you want a GUI that just draws an ellipse, then add the JPanel to a JFrame. If you want to display a GUI that draws an ellipse and displays something else, then add more components. It's all up to you, and even if you do it one way doesn't mean that you won't either change it later or use the same class another way later.

Comment: I think `getContentPane().add(ellipse)` called on the JFrame is fine, but it would be nice to know more about what the ellipse object is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Eclipse a JPanel (or extends some Java Swing container component) or not. 
If not, then go with JPanel solution it will be somewhat treated as a component. If it is then first add a layout manager (BorderLayout perhaps) to JFrame and then add the panel to it may be in CENTER (make your own choice).

My approach for desktop application development has been to:

Add a layout manager to JFrame then add JPanels to JFrame based on the layout. This makes GUI more manageable and easy to update/change in future.

Comment: No Ellipse is just a class which draws a circle.

Comment: Better extend it from JPanel. It gives the Eclipse all Java Swing re-usable Component like behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You might always just draw the ellipse(s) in a `BufferedImage`, add the image to an `ImageIcon` and add the icon to a `JLabel`.